# Phalcon Query builder with column type JSON

Tags: php, postgresql, orm, phalcon

How can I build this query using query builder in Phalcon 2.0.6:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tab1 AS base WHERE (base.col1::jsonb ?| array[ 'foo' ]) ;
```

Column `col1` in table `tab1` has type JSON.

DB Postgresql 9.4

This query works in console.

If i execute query app throw exception with message :

Scanning error before '| array[foo]") ...' when parsing: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS [count] FROM [Tab1] AS [base] WHERE (base.col1::jsonb ?| array[foo]")`

Comment: Read the [phalcon doucmentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html#retrieving-data)

Comment: It's REST API but I need build sql query in phalcon PHQL

Comment: If you have json like
    {"index_name":"foo"}
You can try 
    base.col1:: JSON ->> 'index_name' = 'foo'